# Removing green screen and replacing with alpha in compositor

Tags: rendering

I have a movie with a green screen background. I would like to change the green screen to alpha so I can place a background behind it in the compositor. Could someone give me a link or two???? it would be so appreciated. I could not quite find what I want researching the forum.  Oh it might help to say the movie clip is made up of .PNG files....

Thank you Again!![image]

Comment: Color/Chroma/Luminance Key nodes in compositor https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Thank you!  A simple color key did it.  Could someone tell me what are the typical values for the HSV settings????

[image: simple color key]

Comment: They are tolerances. If your key color has hue 0.33 and H slider is at 0.1, the hue ranges 0.23 - 0.43 (0.33 +- 0.1) will be keyed out. Similarly for others. They completely depend on the source image. A good source image will have very low values for HSV.